# Position fixed for element and centering a div

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I have been working on a countdown plugin for a coming soon page, and you can see it here https://codepen.io/PlatoCode/pen/NRGxBx

As you see the first one, it's exactly in the center but the problem is that I want the last list item which is the seconds to be fixed in position meaning that when the number changes, it doesn't move the other element.

I want it to be fixed so what I do is targeting it and add 'position:fixed' for it but what happens then is that the entire count-down moves a little bit to the right and doesn't become exactly in the center.

Also I have duplicated the code so you can notice the difference. In the second one, there's a class called 'editthis' for the seconds. You can play with it and show me what can be done in order to look the way I want it to look like.

Here is the css code:

```css
#clock {
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#clock li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#clock .seconds {
  /* If I add position: fixed, it moves the entire div to the right a little bit */
}

#clock span {
  font-size: 100px;
}

#clock .smalltext {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<ul id="clockdiv">
  <li>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your codepen is empty ... you need to save it

Comment: The pen has nothing in it ;).

Comment: Your id of ul is "clockdiv" and not "clock"

Comment: OH i'm very sorry guys, I just edited it and put the right one. Here's another copy too https://codepen.io/PlatoCode/pen/NRGxBx

Answer (score 1):

As @kiner_shah said:

Your id of ul is `clockdiv`, not `clock`

Your final code should look something like this:

```css
#clockdiv {
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #clockdiv li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    font-family: "Oswald";
    padding: 0 20px;
  }

  #clockdiv .seconds {
    /* If I add position: fixed, it moves the entire div to the right a little bit */
  }

  #clockdiv span {
    font-size: 100px;
  }

  #clockdiv .smalltext {
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 100;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="clockdiv">
    <li>
      <span class="days"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="hours"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="minutes"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="seconds"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**css**

```
#clockdiv{
background-color:#069;
position:fixed;
width:300px;
height:420px;
top:30%;
left:40%;
}
```

**html**

```
<ul id="clockdiv">
<li>
<span class="days"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Days</div>
</li>
<li> 
<span class="hours"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
</li>
<li>
<span class="minutes"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
</li> 
<li> 
<span class="seconds"></span>
<div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that **removing padding from your li**, and **adding it as a width to your timing span**, you'll be in. Take a look at this snippet.

I removed the margin from your #clockdiv css just to fix it on this page, but you can replace it on your code.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  }
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }
  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 36 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
#clockdiv {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#clockdiv li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  padding: 0;
}
#clockdiv span {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  width:120px; /* current with plus removed padding fro li #clockdiv li */
  font-size: 100px;
}

#clockdiv .smalltext {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<ul id="clockdiv">
  <li>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```